# Why is using final, with no type, considered good practice in Dart? ie `final foo = config.foo;`?

Tags: dart

I see this recommended in the dart [style guide](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style), and copied in tons of tutorials and flutter source.
`final foo = config.foo;`

I don't understand it, how is this considered best practice when the readability is so poor? I have no clue what foo is here, surely `final String foo = config.foo` is preferable if we really want to use final?

This seems the equivalent to using var, which many consider a bad practice because it prevents the compiler from spotting errors and is less readable.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: The rule you are looking for is: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-type-annotating-public-fields-and-top-level-variables-if-the-type-isnt-obvious. In your example, the type is not obvious. In the examples in the style guide, the type is obvious - the right-hand side is either a literal or a constructor invocation.

Comment: Ah, thanks, makes much more sense with that rule also in play.

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of cases is does not really matter what type you are using as long the specific type can be statically determined by the compiler. When you are using var/final in Dart it is not that Dart does not know the type, it will just figure it out automatically based on the context. But the type must still be defined when the program are compiled so the types will never be dynamic based on runtime behavior. If you want truly dynamic types, you can use the `dynamic` keyword where you tell Dart "trust me, I know what I am doing with this types".

So types should still be defined where it matter most. This is e.g. for return and argument types for methods and class variables. The common factor for this types is that they are used to define the interface for using the method or class.

But when you are writing code inside a method, you are often not that interested in the specific types of variables used inside the method. Instead the focus should be the logic itself and you can often make it even more clear by using good describing variable names. As long the Dart analyzer can figure out the type, you will get autocomplete from your IDE and you can even still see the specific type from your IDE by e.g. Ctrl+Q in IntelliJ on the variable if you ends up in a situation where you want to know the type.

This is in particular the case when we are talking about the use of generics where it can be really tiresome to write the full specific type. Especially if you are using multiple generics inside each other like e.g. `Map<String, List<String>>`.

In my experience, Dart is really good to figure out very specific types and will complain loudly if your code cannot be determined statically. In the coming future, Dart will introduce non-null by default, which will make the Dart compiler and analyzer even more powerful since it will make sure your variable cannot be null unless this is something you specifically want and will make sure you are going to test for null when using methods which are specified to not expecting null.

About "Where am I wrong?". Well, a lot of languages have similar feature of var/final like Dart with the same design principle about the type should still be statically determined by a compiler or runtime. And even Java has introducing this feature. As a experienced Java and Dart programmer I have come to the conclusion for myself that typing inside methods are really not that important in a lot of cases as long I can still easily figure out the specific type by using an IDE when it really matters.

But it does make it more important to name your variables so they are clearly defining the purpose. But I am hoping you already are doing that. :)

Comment: Ya, I'm familiar with inference in dart, and agree it's really good! Totally disagree that it's not important to see types inside of methods though. Especially on a team of developers, it's extremely helpful to see clearly defined types when trying to grokk some code.